# Can I omit an article when it's an infographic?

Tags: articles

Recently my company became an ambassador of a certain XYZ technology. We have designed a picture where we brag about it: "We are XYZ ambassador and 2nd biggest contributor".

Now, the question is: can we omit "a" - "We are an XYZ ambassador and 2nd biggest contributor". ?

Comment: Although certain humanitarian organisations have (often celebrity) ambassadors to promote their interests, companies generally have representatives or public relations firms to represent and promote their products. In what sense is your company an "ambassador" of a technology? What is your function?

Comment: I would not omit *an* before *XYZ ambassador*. Nor would I omit *the* before *2nd*. (But this example is also a bit contrived, because *XYZ ambassador* doesn't mean anything to me (nor is it usual for a group of people to be a single ambassador)—so I'm talking only about the syntax itself.)

Comment: It is common to drop articles in headlines and captions. It is less clear (are you one of many ambassadors or the only one) but it looks punchier.

Answer (score 0):

I would use either:

> We are an ambassador of XYZ and their second-biggest contributor.

Or:

> We are XYZ ambassadors and their second-biggest contributor.

In short, I think a determiner should be used for both *ambassador* and *contributor*; your sentence sounds incomplete and a little confusing without them.

Comment: The lack of determiner only works with the plural. The question asks about the singular.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *we are ambassador* without an article, *ambassador* becomes abstract.

Consider saying something like *I am water* - here, you are speaking as though you are what water is to all people.  That's typically not valid so no one says that.

Adding to the confusion specifically with the word *ambassador* is the fact that *ambassador* is something like a "royal title".  Consider saying *I am king* - you usually don't have to say *I am the king*.  Titles of family can be like that too: like Mother, Father, etc.  This is an expression of respect/deference (essentially these titles are allowed to assume they apply on a "blueprint" or abstract level even though they really don't).

But when you say *I am XYZ ambassador* you are already admitting that you are not the "royal title" ambassador but just that of a specific group--a specific group that actually exists and is not abstract.  Articles are required unless nouns are proper or abstract.  Therefore you have to use the article.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is an infographic, you may use "bullet points"

> **Company Name**
>
> - XYZ ambassador
> - 2nd largest contributor
> - Handsome CEO
> - Other claim

In prose you would need an article, but then you need to say if you a "an" ambassador (one of many) or "the ambassador" (there can be only one).  And it is worth saying that the use of "ambassador" in this context seems strange to me.